# How to create a map of a fictional place with Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, customization

The wiki for one of the video games I play has a map of the game world powered by Google Maps.  You can see the map [**here**](http://www.uesp.net/maps/obmap/obmap.shtml).

How would I go about creating a map like this for my own project?

Is this done through the Google Maps API?

Comment: Nice writeup on how someone did this for World of Warcraft: http://www.iamcal.com/world-of-mapcraft/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The Google Maps API has a [custom map tiles](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#CustomMapTiles) feature.